# No Impalad available

Tags: emr, hue, impala

I'm setting up Hue 3.8.1 to point to EMR

I've received the following message from check_config:

```
Impala Editor   No available Impalad to send queries to.
```

I've confirmed that impala is running on my host (the EMR master node), and tat a connection can be made using impyla.

What am I missing here?

the host and port are correctly set

```
# Host of the Impala Server (one of the Impalad)
server_host=192.168.16.231

# Port of the Impala Server
server_port=21050
```

Comment: You need to make sure Hue is configured to point to this Impalad: http://gethue.com/how-to-configure-hue-in-your-hadoop-cluster/

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: I don't know about consensus in that topic, but "Hue" is not a tag, it's the key part of the title. See meta.stackexchange.com/a/179969/131861

Comment: @Nickolay *hue* is a tag ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hue